# sending DATETIME parameters to SP from Method Call In C# Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, stored-procedures, dapper

I have following SP in SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGetData] 

       @StartDate DATETIME,
       @EndDate DATETIME

AS
            BEGIN
                  SELECT *
                  FROM SampleTable
                  WHERE CAST(SampleTable.CreateDate AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)                   
            END
END
GO
```

When I test this SP from Management Studio this is working fine , But I should Pass  StartDate and EndDate  values as following

[image]

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPGetStationData]
        @StartDate = N'2016/10/08',
        @EndDate = N'2016/10/09'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I want to send parameters from my back end c# program ,

So created method as following

```
    public IEnumerable<ModelClass> GetDetails(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = this.OpenConnection())
        {

            DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@StartDate", startdate);
            parameters.Add("@EndDate", enddate);

            IList<ModelClass> SampleList = SqlMapper.Query<ModelClass>(cnn, "SPGetData", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

            cnn.Close();

            return SampleList.ToList();
        }
    }
```

But when I debug this I can see values coming to this method as 
in Following format

[image]

in Stored Procedure asking `YYYY/MM/DD` format but I have here in `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM/PM` format

what should I do to do this to acceptable with SP asking format

Comment: Are you getting any error? Usually, it is automatically resolved and sql server gets date time in correct format.

Comment: No I'm not getting any error even , just saying results is zero

Comment: The SP accepts a DATETIME which means you can pass a string (or varchar) in any format SQL Server understands, you are not limited to yyyy/mm/dd.  Use the `.Add` overload that allows you to specify a DateTime datatype to avoid these issues/ambiguities.

Comment: No you are not getting a different 'format' It is the VS debugger that display your dates according to your international settings. The DateTime variable is not passed as a string albeit using a precise parameter type would help. You have not told us if the sp returns the correct data despite datetime are in an incorrect 'format' .

Comment: What is `SqlMapper` thing?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Its Dapper , we can use to call SP , other than SQL commands

Comment: @Steve I usually use Dapper like `con.Query<T>("proc", new {startDate, endDate}, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);` and never got any issue

Comment: Are you getting any results when executing command in Management Studio? Can you turn on logging/tracing?

Comment: When I check this through MS studio results are ok , How use logging/tracing

Comment: @AlexK. are you saying use parameters like following `public IEnumerable<ModelClass> GetDetails(string startdate, string enddate)` ?

Comment: Will you try this once: `cnn.Query<ModelClass>("SPGetData", new { startDate.Value, endDate.Value}, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();`

Comment: Have you used Sql Server Profiler to see what is actually being sent? That can help you rule out if its an issue with what you are supplying Dapper o something else like unexpected data.

Comment: @Igor I havent use  `Sql Server Profiler` can you recommend good article

Comment: No, not off my head. Its easy though, just open the app, point it to the database server, and start profiling. You will get all activity in the profiler, you can narrow it down by adding filters, and also extend what is logged. Give it a shot, its fairly straight forward.

Comment: @Igor okay thanks I'll go through that one also

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot when I defined as you said following `IList<ModelClass> SampleList = cnn.Query<ModelClass>("SPGetData", new { startdate.Value , enddate.Value }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();` compile time error on 'enddate.Value' getting error as  `An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name`

Comment: aha, try this `new {StartDate = startdate.Value, EndDate=enddate.Value}`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot when I put like that getting error like following http://i.imgur.com/CUMXFnp.png

Comment: try with this startdate.ToShortDateTimeString() then pass as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My working code,

```
// Store procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPGetData] 
       @StartDate nvarchar(50) = null, -- change 
       @EndDate nvarchar(50) = null -- change 
AS
    BEGIN
       -- change  in where condition
       SELECT *
       FROM SampleTable
       WHERE 
        DATEPART(yyyy,cast(SampleTable.CreateDate as date)) BETWEEN DATEPART(yyyy,cast(@StartDate as date)) and DATEPART(yyyy,cast(@EndDate as date))
    END
END
GO

// Visual Studio Code for dapper
public IEnumerable<ModelClass> GetDetails(DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
    {

var _para = new DynamicParameters();
    _para.Add("@StartDate", startdate);
    _para.Add("@EndDate", enddate);
    var _list = _con.Query<ModelClass>("SPGetData", _para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); // _con is SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection("your connection string")
            return _list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me.

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime? s=null;
    DateTime? e=DateTime.Today;
    Test(s,e);
}

void Test(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    var cs=@"data source=(local);database=test;integrated security=true";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        var t = con.Query<string>("TestIt", new { startDate, endDate},
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        $"List: {t.FirstOrDefault()}".Dump();
    }
}
```

Here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROC TestIt
(
    @startDate datetime2,
    @endDate datetime2
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Start: ' + CASE WHEN @startDate IS NULL THEN 'Null' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), @startDate, 106) END +
            '\r\nEnd: ' + CASE WHEN @endDate IS NULL THEN 'Null' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), @endDate, 106) END
END
```

Just note that unlike the code in comment I'm not defining any property names when passing parameters:

```
new { startDate, endDate}
```

As the procedure parameter names are same as the variable that I'm passing to the method. To use same code as in comment, you can modify it as this:

```
cnn.Query<ModelClass>("SPGetData",  
   new { StartDate=startDate??null, EndDate=endDate??null}, 
    commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList()
```